# Find memory leaks in the Activity code to free memory usage and avoid OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, leakcanary

I have an `Activity` with a `ConstraingLayout` with lots of `ImageView`s (one per card).

After a win, by clicking on the ImageView that will appear, the `Activity` will be "reloaded" showing a new set of cards to play.

The problem is that after each win the memory used by the `Activity` raises instead of returning at the initial amount used.

This cause an `OutOfMemory Exception` on some devices with low memory (e.g. on Nexus 7). :(

The logics are:

- in the `onCreate` method I set the `ConstraintLayout` made of 30 `ImageView`s (the front side of rhe cards) and others 30 `ImageView`s (the back side of the cards)
- for each `ImageView` (front and back sides) I set the `OnClickListener` and the image by scaling the drawable resource
- every time the user clicks on an `ImageView`, I set the alpha for the two sides of the card to show only the proper side
- if the user finds all matches, the win View will appear: if the user clicks it, will be invoked the win method, which "reload the activity"

**GiocaMemory.java**:

```
package ...
import ...

public class GiocaMemory extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ...

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListenerReleaseMediaPlayer;

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener onAudioFocusChangeListener;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        onCompletionListenerReleaseMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        };

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        onAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange)
            {
                if(mediaPlayer != null)
                {
                    switch (focusChange)
                    {
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                            break;
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            break;
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                            releaseMediaPlayer();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        ...
    }

    private void win()
    {
        showView(textViewWin);
    }

    public void reloadActivity()
    {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }

    public void playSound(int idElement)
    {
        String name = idElement + "_name";

        playAudio(name, onCompletionListenerReleaseMediaPlayer);
    }

    public void playAudioName(int idElement)
    {
        String name = idElement + "_sound";

        playAudio(name, onCompletionListenerReleaseMediaPlayer);
    }

    public void onClickHome(View view)
    {
        finish();
    }

    public void stopAudio()
    {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void playAudio(String audioName, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener)
    {
        stopAudio();

        if(!audioName.isEmpty())
        {
            int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
            {
                int resID = res.getIdentifier(audioName, "raw", getPackageName());

                if (resID == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                releaseMediaPlayer();

                startMediaPlayerWithRes(this, resID, audioName);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);

            }
        }
    }

    private void startMediaPlayerWithRes(Context context, int resID, String audioName)
    {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, resID);

        if(mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.start();
        else mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer()
    {
        if(mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    private void loadContents()
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void freeRes()
    {
        ...

        mediaPlayer = null;
        onCompletionListenerReleaseMediaPlayer = null;

        audioManager = null;
        onAudioFocusChangeListener = null;
        res = null;

        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        freeRes();
    }
}
```

At the first run of `GiocaMemory` the `AndroidStudio`'s `profiler` is:

[image]

After a win (so after the second `onCreate`) the used memory is:

[image]

Now the `Java` memory usage is `28,1 MB`, instead of returning at the initial value of `25,2 MB`.

The screenshots refer to the layout with 16 boxes. **With the 30 box layout the memory used increases a lot more. (E.g. from 49 MB to 83 MB)**

I may say that the images are enough resized in order to use the less memory possible, so maybe they cannot be the problem. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

- Why after every win the MB used by `Java` will increase?
- Can you please help me find some memory leaks I left in the code?
- The way I'm using to "reload" the `GiocaMemory` Activity is correct or there is an other way which let me free more resources?

I'm find very very hard to find them because I'm relatively new to Android programming, especially since I almost never had to face problems related to excessive memory usage.

**Edit**:

These are some info using [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/):

[image]

By clicking on one of the 3 "GiocaMemory Leaked 21 Agosto 13:35" (all 3 are the same, changing only the `key =` at the end of the trace)

```
ApplicationLeak(className=app.myapp.GiocaMemory, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.media.AudioManager$1
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous subclass of android.media.IAudioFocusDispatcher$Stub
│    GC Root: Global variable in native code
│    ↓ AudioManager$1.this$0
│                     ~~~~~~
├─ android.media.AudioManager
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ AudioManager.mAudioFocusIdListenerMap
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ HashMap.table
│              ~~~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array HashMap$HashMapEntry[].[0]
│                                   ~~~
├─ java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ HashMap$HashMapEntry.value
│                           ~~~~~
├─ app.myapp.GiocaMemory$2
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous class implementing android.media.AudioManager$OnAudioFocusChangeListener
│    ↓ GiocaMemory$2.this$0
│                    ~~~~~~
╰→ app.myapp.GiocaMemory
​     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
​     key = dfa0d5fe-0c50-4c64-a399-b5540eb686df
​     watchDurationMillis = 380430
​     retainedDurationMillis = 375425
, retainedHeapByteSize=470627)
```

The [official LeakCanary's documentation](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals/#narrowing-down-the-cause-of-a-leak) says:

> If a node is not leaking, then any prior reference that points to it is not the source of the leak, and also not leaking. Similarly, if a node is leaking then any node down the leak trace is also leaking. From that, we can deduce that the leak is caused by a reference that is after the last `Leaking: NO` and before the first `Leaking: YES`.

But in my leakTrace there are only `UNKNOWN` leaks exept the last `YES`.

How can I find that `YES` leak in my code, if it maybe a leak?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The screenshots are nice, but don't really show the problem. That the `JVM` increases the memory can be considered normal. If you can, add a screenshot which shows the usage till the crash happens. -- Also what are the memory limitation you have applied to your `jvm` (include the vm parameters into your question)? -- Consider profiling your app as well.

Comment: You can select a range in that profile, to observe the allocations between a start/end time of your choice. It will show you what your GC is keeping in memory, what is keeping said allocations in memory, and therefore, it will point you to the code where you are allocating memory; hopefully this will help you find the code you didn't write: deallocate the memory.

Comment: You really need to load hold your list of imageviews like that? I mean, couldn't you used recyclerview instead?

Comment: @second I can't post the screenshot on of the old device because it wan't connect to the pc. I don't setted any limit in the jvm, I'm using real devices. How can I profile the app? Please suggest to me a link with video/examples

Comment: I selected a range in the profiling (from before the win and after it) but here it show me only the amount of object types and not the variable names used in my code: is't true or I'm doing something wrong? You say "it will point you to the code where you are allocating memory": did you mean that the profiler can tell me the exact code raw where the memory leaks is?

Comment: @user2342558 yeah probably you'll need to! but if you have a list with a lot of images, and they're not visible at the same time, i guess recyclerview is the way to go, it'll handle your resources when they're not visible on the screen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you properly abandoning the focus listener from AudioManager?

`AudioManager#abandonAudioFocus(OnAudioFocusChangeListener listener)`

The actual OOM might be the result of non recycling lists as mentioned, but that could be the cause of your memory leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves the leak! Now the app has no leaks!